# Column neither grouped nor aggregated after introducing window query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I have trouble integrating a simple window function into my query. I work with [this avocado dataset from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/neuromusic/avocado-prices). I started off with a simple query:

```
SELECT
  date,
  SUM(Total_Bags) as weekly_bags,
FROM 
  `course.avocado`
WHERE
  EXTRACT(year FROM date) = 2015
GROUP BY
  date
ORDER BY
  date
```

And it works just fine. Next, I want to add the rolling sum to the query to display along the weekly sum. I tried the following:

```
SELECT
  date,
  SUM(Total_Bags) as weekly_bags,
  SUM(Total_Bags) OVER(
    PARTITION BY date
    ORDER BY date
    ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
  )
FROM 
  `course.avocado`
WHERE
  EXTRACT(year FROM date) = 2015
GROUP BY
  date
ORDER BY
  date
```

but im getting the common error:

> SELECT list expression references column Total_Bags which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [4:7]

and im confused. Total_Bags in the first query was aggregated yet when it's introduced again in the second query, it's not aggregated anymore. How do I fix this query? Thanks.

Comment: provide simple example of input data and expected output (please do not use images  - use text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, which returns 2 columns: `date` and aggregate `SUM(Total_Bags)`, the window function `SUM()` is evaluated after the aggregation when there is no column `Total_Bags` and  this is why you can't use it inside the window function.

However, you can do want you want, without `group by`, by using only window functions and `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date,
       SUM(Total_Bags) OVER(PARTITION BY date) AS weekly_bags,
       SUM(Total_Bags) OVER(
         PARTITION BY date
         ORDER BY date
         ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
       )
FROM course.avocado
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM date) = 2015
ORDER BY date;
```

or, use window function on the the aggregated result:

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(Total_Bags) AS weekly_bags,
       SUM(SUM(Total_Bags)) OVER(
         ORDER BY date
         ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
       )
FROM course.avocado
WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM date) = 2015
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: thanks @forpas. I ran this code and it executes correctly but the `DISTINCT` somehow doesn't work as expected. In the query result, there are 100+ records for each date, with identical `weekly_bags` sum and different `rolling_sum` (rightly so). Maybe grouping is a must here?

Comment: @ppp147 that depends on your expected result. If you want aggregation on the aggregated values of weekly_bags and not on Total_bags check my 2nd query.

Comment: thanks, the second code works just fine. I appreciate!

Comment: @ppp147 fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to approach it from a different angle and seems I have figured it out, the results seem just right. Here's the code:

```
WITH daily_bags AS
  (SELECT
    Date,
    CAST(SUM(Total_Bags) as int64) as all_bags
  FROM
    `course.avocado`
  WHERE 
    EXTRACT(year from Date) = 2015
  GROUP BY
    Date
  ORDER BY
    Date)

SELECT
  Date,
  all_bags,
  SUM(all_bags) OVER(
    ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) as rolling_sum
FROM
  daily_bags
```

Thanks everyone for your help.